# Xcode Parse Issue Expected identifier?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

So I'm getting this error "Xcode Parse Issue Expected identifier?" at the end of this line of code

```
    NSArray *paths = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)];
```

I've looked all over and can't figure out what it is that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You don't need the brackets.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask why though? I'm new to objective-c, coming from c++, and I don't really understand what the brackets are for in the first place when you're setting a variable to equal something.

Comment: That's just the way it goes with Objective-C.  You'll get used to it.

Comment: It is simple when you are calling C-Like functions `type functionName(params ..);` you don't need the Brackets, but when you are calling obj-c method like `- (type)functionName:(param)nameParam ...;` you need.